# Solving some constraints on a subgroup of a Lie group

Tags: equation-solving, algebraic-manipulation, algebra, group-theory, constraint

Let $M$ be a rank-3 matrix, I am interested in searching all the group elements $g \in$ SU(3) Lie group, such that,

> $$
> g^T M g =M.
> $$

**Example 1**. Let 
$$
M[1]=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
then we can find that there is at least a subgroup $g \in SU(2) \subset SU(3)$ that makes the $M[1]$ satisfies 
$$
g^T M[1] g =M[1],
$$
the 
$$ g = \exp\left(\theta\sum_{k=1}^{3} i t_k \frac{\sigma_k}{2}\right)  
=\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})+i \sum_{k=1}^{3}  t_k \sigma_k\sin(\frac{\theta}{2})$$

\begin{align}
  \sigma_1 = \sigma_x =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&1 & 0\\
      1&0 & 0\\
0&0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix},
  \sigma_2 = \sigma_y =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&-i& 0\\
      i&0& 0\\
 0 & 0& 0
    \end{pmatrix},
  \sigma_3 = \sigma_z =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      1&0& 0\\
      0&-1& 0\\
 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix} \,.
\end{align}
Notice that any group element on $SU(2)$ can be parametrized by some $\theta$ and $(t_1,t_2,t_3)$. Also $\theta$ has a periodicity $[0,4 \pi)$.

**Example 2**. Let 
$$
M[1]=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
M[2]=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
M[3]=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$

> Can we find some subgroup $g \in G \subset$  SU(3) Lie group? such that
>   $$ 
> g^T \{M[1], M[2], M[3]\} g =\{M[1], M[2], M[3]\}
> $$
>   This means that $g^TM[a]g=M[b]$ which may transform $a$ to a different value $b$. But overall the full set $ \{M[1], M[2], M[3]\}$ is invariant under the transformation?

**Example 3**. . Let 
$$
M[1]=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
M[2]=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
M[3]=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$
$$
M[4]=
-\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
M[5]=
-\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),
M[6]=-\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),$$

> Can we find some subgroup $g \in G \subset$  SU(3) Lie group? such that
>   $$ 
> g^T \{M[1], M[2], M[3],M[4], M[5], M[6]\} g =\{M[1], M[2], M[3],M[4], M[5], M[6]\}
> $$
>   This means that $g^TM[a]g=M[b]$ which may transform $a$ to a different value $b$. But overall the full set $ \{M[1], M[2], M[3],M[4], M[5], M[6]\}$ is invariant under the transformation?

How can we write a Mathematica .nb file to solve this?

(Of course, there is always a trivial solution the identity $g=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$), but what are other solutions?